# Adobe Typekit Fonts

Tags: xetex, fontspec, adobe, mac

Adobe Typekit fonts install themselves in application fontlists (Word, InDesign etc.) but do not install in the Mac Fontbook. They are rented so this is their way of enforcing licence terms.

Since they are effectively hidden in the directory structure, I cannot find a way of using them in Latex documents with the fontspec package.

Has anyone managed to work around this and use them with fontspec??

Comment: Why don't you install them manually? I have not try yet to use `fontspec` on Mac.

Comment: Can you find the actual .ttf files on the computer somewhere? If so you could try using the full path or making an alias.

Comment: Web fonts are optimized for screen; for print typography, you want fonts made for printing.

Comment: @AndrewCashner I think those fonts are OpenType and not TrueType.

Comment: @Thérèse Those fonts are for print and web also, in fact I don't know which are for web, but the most are for printing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257422/where-does-adobe-cc-store-typekit-files-locally

Comment: If you know where the `.ttf` file is stored, I believe that `fontspec` will happily find it if you use the `Path=...` option.

Answer (score 6):

The [tutorial](http://dylanvalade.com/post/74649521957/how-to-find-synced-typekit-fonts-on-your-computer) referenced from stackoverflow answer in the comment by Andrew Cashner provides most of what you need.  After syncing the font with TypeKit, we need to find the file which is hidden in one of the Adobe support directories

Here's a short summary of the steps in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE 
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Adobe/CoreSync/plugins/livetype/.r/
open .
```

this opens a finder window, then we need to "Get Info" on the files so we can see the name of the font.  Then, for example, I found that ".22140.otf" was really Petalo Pro Bold:

```
cp .22140.otf ~/myproject/petalo-pro-bold.otf
```

Then the easiest way to use it is with XeLaTeX. The following code is from one of the templates that ships with TexShop:

```
% XeLaTeX can use any Mac OS X font. See the setromanfont command below.
% Input to XeLaTeX is full Unicode, so Unicode characters can be typed directly into the source.

% The next lines tell TeXShop to typeset with xelatex, and to open and save the source with Unicode encoding.

%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% Will Robertson's fontspec.sty can be used to simplify font choices.
% To experiment, open /Applications/Font Book to examine the fonts provided on Mac OS X,
% and change "Hoefler Text" to any of these choices.

\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\setmainfont{petalo-pro-bold.otf}

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

which generates this PDF:

[image]

Comment: **xltxtra** is largely deprecated.

Comment: removed xltxtra, example works fine without it and its docs says fontspec loads it anyhow

Comment: I think the docs are lying. Maybe it used to load it.

Comment: @cfr do you have a reference to it being deprecated and why?  it is still part of the default template in TeXShop 2015

Comment: Just read the `README` for the package, but it has also be mentioned several times on this site so you could also search. You don't need to load **xunicode** either as it will be loaded by **fontspec** anyway.

Comment: from xltxtra README:  This package was previous used to provide a number of small features that are useful for XeLaTeX. As of fontspec v2, many of these have now been incorporated into that package.
This package therefore no longer does as much as it used to,
but is still provided for backwards compatibility.  -- I guess the makers of TeXShop still find it useful or otherwise didn't think to remove it.  Not what I would normally call "deprecated" but seems not to be needed.

Comment: I was just going by what people have said in discussion here about it being better not to use it now unless you specifically need it. I just meant the README explained the changes.

Comment: @cfr thanks!  I'm new to latex, and was answering this question as a way to learn.  It's great to have the extra info on best practices.